# Django: assertEquals with visually equal result with QuerySet

Tags: python, django, testing, automated-tests, comparison

Can anybody explain me why these have the same values, but don't compare equal? Having a bit of a hard time to understand that. And what would be the best way to make them be "equal"?

Inspection using ipdb:

```
ipdb> expected_value                                                                                                                                  
{'author': 'john', 'id': 1, 'title': 'Yesterday', 'body': 'All my troubles seemed so far away', 'tags': <QuerySet ['Music', 'Lyrics']>}
ipdb> response                                                                                                                                        
{'author': 'john', 'id': 1, 'title': 'Yesterday', 'body': 'All my troubles seemed so far away', 'tags': <QuerySet ['Music', 'Lyrics']>}
```

Pieces of code:

```
class TestPost(TestCase):                                                                                               

    def test_serialize(self):                                                                                           
        user = User.objects.create(username="john", password="12345678", email="john@exemplo.com")                      
        tag1 = Tag.objects.create(value="Music")                                                                        
        tag2 = Tag.objects.create(value="Lyrics")                                                                       
        post = Post.objects.create(author=user, title="Yesterday", body="All my troubles seemed so far away")           
        post.tags.add(tag1)                                                                                             
        post.tags.add(tag2)                                                                                             

        expected_value = {                                                                                              
            "author": user.username,                                                                                    
            "id": user.id,                                                                                              
            "title": post.title,                                                                                        
            "body": post.body,                                                                                          
            "tags": post.tags.all().values_list("value", flat=True),                                                    
        }                                                                                                               
        response = post.serialize()                                                                                                                                      
        self.assertEqual(expected_value, response)
```

and the Django model that I was testing

```
class Post(models.Model):                                                                                               
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False,)            
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)], max_length=50)                
    body = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)], max_length=1000)               
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag")                                                                                

    def serialize(self):                                                                                                
        return {                                                                                                        
            "author": self.author.username,                                                                             
            "id": self.id,                                                                                              
            "title": self.title,                                                                                        
            "body": self.body,                                                                                          
            "tags": self.tags.all().values_list("value", flat=True),                                                    
        }
```

Comment: A queryset is not equal, not even to one with the same values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anybody explain me why these have the same values, but don't compare equal?

Because two [**`QuerySet`** objects [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/query.py#L184) are not considered equal when they "carry" the same values. Only if the object itself is the same, it will be considered equal. Indeed, if you test this in the shell, you retrieve:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all() == MyModel.objects.all()
False
>>> qs = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> qs == qs
True
```

After all a `QuerySet` is not only a collection of values, but also a query, and checking if two queries are equivalent, is probably an [*undeciable problem* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem).

You thus can convert this to a list with `list(…)`, for example:

```
expected_value = {
    'author': user.username,
    'id': user.id,
    'title': post.title,
    'body': post.body,
    'tags': list(post.tags.values_list('value', flat=True)),
}
```

as well as in the serializer:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)], max_length=50)
    body = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)], max_length=1000)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag")

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'author': self.author.username,
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'body': self.body,
            'tags': list(self.tags.values_list('value', flat=True))
        }
```